# mySQL pivot dynamic dates table

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table, crosstab

i am running my query

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(st_day_request) -MOD(TO_DAYS(st_day_request) -2, 7)), '%d-%m-%Y') as DATE,
tx_report_id AS 'BUSINESS',
CONCAT(ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dt_dossier_sent,st_day_request) > -5 AND (main.dt_dossier_sent IS NOT NULL AND main.dt_dossier_sent <> '0000-00-00')) * 100),'%') as DISPATCHED_5_AND_MORE,
CONCAT(ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dt_dossier_sent,st_day_request) < -5 AND DATEDIFF(dt_dossier_sent,st_day_request) <= 1 AND (main.dt_dossier_sent IS NOT NULL AND main.dt_dossier_sent <> '0000-00-00')) * 100),'%') as DISPATCHED_4_TO_1,
CONCAT(ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dt_dossier_sent,st_day_request) > 1 AND DATEDIFF(dt_dossier_sent,st_day_request) <= 10 AND (main.dt_dossier_sent IS NOT NULL AND main.dt_dossier_sent <> '0000-00-00')) * 100),'%') as DISPATCHED_2_TO_10,
CONCAT(ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dt_dossier_sent,st_day_request) > 10 AND (main.dt_dossier_sent IS NOT NULL AND main.dt_dossier_sent <> '0000-00-00')) * 100),'%') as DISPATCHED_10_AND_MORE,
CONCAT(ROUND(AVG(main.dt_dossier_sent IS NULL OR main.dt_dossier_sent = '0000-00-00') * 100),'%') as OUTSTANDING FROM
(
SELECT 
    app_contract.id_app,
    app_contract.dt_dossier_sent,
    contract.tx_report_id,
    contract.st_day_request
FROM
    contract
INNER JOIN app_contract ON  app_contract.id_contract = contract.id_contract  AND contract.st_day_request > '2017-09-01' AND contract.id_client = 657
INNER JOIN app_hist ON app_hist.id_app=app_contract.id_app
GROUP BY app_contract.id_app
) as main GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(st_day_request, '%y') ASC, DATE_FORMAT(st_day_request, '%m') ASC
```

and getting the results on the image below:

[image: Results from my query]

Up to here, everything is correct. The Problem i have is that i want to change (pivot/crosstab) my results and put the dates i get as Columns, as you can see in the next image below:

[image: Result i need to get]

I am trying for a couple of days but unfortunately without result. Any ideas?

PS. If you cannot see the images properly, please right click and open in new tab. Then you can enlarge them. Sorry for the images, i will copy-and paste the results in my next post.

Comment: please, don't put pictures but just copy-paste the kind of results you want. This is unreadable.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I'm with @Strawberry : pivoting in pure MySQL is a notorious pain in the neck, especially when you want to control the number and meaning of your columns via the data in your table.  Use some reporting language, or maybe even export to a csv file and use a spreadsheet program.

Comment: I need to do it with mySql. The alternative would be to use php, so this would be easy. I am trying to see if it can be done by using mySql

Answer (score 0):

Follow the tags -- there are many examples of how to do it in MySQL.  Also, here is an automated way to generate SQL from a MySQL Stored Procedure:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

(Personally, I use generic PHP code that turns a 3-column table into a matrix.)